# Bootstrap 4 center aligned navbar issue

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar

I have been struggling with this, mainly because I'm a novice and it seems a inconsistent. I have not built a site from scratch in many years.

I have customized a nav bar and wanted to customize the toggler button. A kind person helped me get it mainly straight.

But the solution puts my navbar to the left. No matter where or how (text align-center, justify-center, etc...) every method I can find, and every where I put this attribute, it changes nothing.

AND why in the heck does Home stay like it is hovered?

I have uploaded to drafts to test.

In this one, the toggle button is great when smooshed narrow, except that once clicked, it's appearance changes. And the navbar is aligned left. And the Home button stays blue when it should be yellow.

https://www.walterbeckham.com/testingzone/two.html

This one, the navbar is centered but the toggle button is not how it should be.

https://www.walterbeckham.com/testingzone/two.html

The only difference between these two that I can see is a tiny snippet of code about the toggler-custom. They are both drawing from the same css sheet.

I have compared the two documents side by side, omitted and added to try to see just what is controlling what, but I just don't get it.

Below is every bit of code that relates to the nav in bootstrap's css. As you know, most of this just came in the new site when I started this project.

```
.nav {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-link {
  color: #FFCC00;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}

.nav-link:hover, .nav-link:focus {
    color: #33CCFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-link.disabled {
  color: #6c757d;
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}

.nav-tabs {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dee2e6;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-item {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-link {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top-left-radius: 0.25rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-link:hover, .nav-tabs .nav-link:focus {
  border-color: #e9ecef #e9ecef #dee2e6;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-link.disabled {
  color: #6c757d;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-link.active,
.nav-tabs .nav-item.show .nav-link {
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #dee2e6 #dee2e6 #fff;
}

.nav-tabs .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: -1px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

.nav-pills .nav-link {
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.nav-pills .nav-link.active,
.nav-pills .show > .nav-link {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #007bff;
}

.nav-fill .nav-item {
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-justified .nav-item {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
  flex-basis: 0;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.tab-content > .tab-pane {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content > .active {
  display: block;
}

.navbar {
  position: relative;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}

.navbar .container,
.navbar .container-fluid, .navbar .container-sm, .navbar .container-md, .navbar .container-lg, .navbar .container-xl {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar-custom {
    background-color: #0a0a0a;
}
/* change the brand and text color */

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand,
.navbar-custom .navbar-text {
    color: rgba(243, 203, 4, 1);
}
/* change the link color */
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
/* change the color of active or hovered links */
.navbar-custom .nav-item.active .nav-link,
.navbar-custom .nav-item:hover .nav-link {
    color: #33ccff;
}

.navbar-brand {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 0.3125rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.3125rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.navbar-brand:hover, .navbar-brand:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-nav {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
  position: static;
  float: none;
}

.navbar-text {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.navbar-collapse {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.custom-toggler .navbar-toggler {
   color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
   border-color: #f3cb06;
   background-color: #0A0A0A;
    text-align: center
} 

.custom-toggler .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(243,203,6,1)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

//change toggler color

.custom-toggler.navbar-toggler {
    border-color: #ffcc00;
    text-align: center
}
    
//end change toggler color but I need to change the toggler bg color

.navbar-toggler {
  padding: 0.25rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.navbar-toggler:hover, .navbar-toggler:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-toggler-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: "";
  background: no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
  .navbar-expand-sm > .container,
  .navbar-expand-sm > .container-fluid, .navbar-expand-sm > .container-sm, .navbar-expand-sm > .container-md, .navbar-expand-sm > .container-lg, .navbar-expand-sm > .container-xl {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .navbar-expand-sm {
    -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
  .navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav {
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
  }
  .navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
  }
  .navbar-expand-sm > .container,
  .navbar-expand-sm > .container-fluid, .navbar-expand-sm > .container-sm, .navbar-expand-sm > .container-md, .navbar-expand-sm > .container-lg, .navbar-expand-sm > .container-xl {
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
  .navbar-expand-sm .navbar-collapse {
    display: -ms-flexbox !important;
    display: flex !important;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: auto;
    flex-basis: auto;
  }
  .navbar-expand-sm .navbar-toggler {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .navbar-expand-md > .container,
  .navbar-expand-md > .container-fluid, .navbar-expand-md > .container-sm, .navbar-expand-md > .container-md, .navbar-expand-md > .container-lg, .navbar-expand-md > .container-xl {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-expand-md {
    -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
  .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav {
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
  }
  .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
  }
  .navbar-expand-md > .container,
  .navbar-expand-md > .container-fluid, .navbar-expand-md > .container-sm, .navbar-expand-md > .container-md, .navbar-expand-md > .container-lg, .navbar-expand-md > .container-xl {
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
  .navbar-expand-md .navbar-collapse {
    display: -ms-flexbox !important;
    display: flex !important;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: auto;
    flex-basis: auto;
  }
  .navbar-expand-md .navbar-toggler {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
  .navbar-expand-lg > .container,
  .navbar-expand-lg > .container-fluid, .navbar-expand-lg > .container-sm, .navbar-expand-lg > .container-md, .navbar-expand-lg > .container-lg, .navbar-expand-lg > .container-xl {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .navbar-expand-lg {
    -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    background-color: #000000;
  }
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav {
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
  }
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
  }
  .navbar-expand-lg > .container,
  .navbar-expand-lg > .container-fluid, .navbar-expand-lg > .container-sm, .navbar-expand-lg > .container-md, .navbar-expand-lg > .container-lg, .navbar-expand-lg > .container-xl {
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-collapse {
    display: -ms-flexbox !important;
    display: flex !important;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: auto;
    flex-basis: auto;
  }
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-toggler {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1199.98px) {
  .navbar-expand-xl > .container,
  .navbar-expand-xl > .container-fluid, .navbar-expand-xl > .container-sm, .navbar-expand-xl > .container-md, .navbar-expand-xl > .container-lg, .navbar-expand-xl > .container-xl {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .navbar-expand-xl {
    -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
  .navbar-expand-xl .navbar-nav {
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .navbar-expand-xl .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
  }
  .navbar-expand-xl .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
  }
  .navbar-expand-xl > .container,
  .navbar-expand-xl > .container-fluid, .navbar-expand-xl > .container-sm, .navbar-expand-xl > .container-md, .navbar-expand-xl > .container-lg, .navbar-expand-xl > .container-xl {
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
  .navbar-expand-xl .navbar-collapse {
    display: -ms-flexbox !important;
    display: flex !important;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: auto;
    flex-basis: auto;
  }
  .navbar-expand-xl .navbar-toggler {
    display: none;
  }
}

.navbar-expand {
  -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.navbar-expand > .container,
.navbar-expand > .container-fluid, .navbar-expand > .container-sm, .navbar-expand > .container-md, .navbar-expand > .container-lg, .navbar-expand > .container-xl {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.navbar-expand .navbar-nav {
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.navbar-expand .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
}

.navbar-expand .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
}

.navbar-expand > .container,
.navbar-expand > .container-fluid, .navbar-expand > .container-sm, .navbar-expand > .container-md, .navbar-expand > .container-lg, .navbar-expand > .container-xl {
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.navbar-expand .navbar-collapse {
  display: -ms-flexbox !important;
  display: flex !important;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: auto;
  flex-basis: auto;
}

.navbar-expand .navbar-toggler {
  display: none;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-brand {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.navbar-light .navbar-brand:hover, .navbar-light .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.disabled {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link,
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link,
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.show,
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='30' height='30' viewBox='0 0 30 30'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

.navbar-light .navbar-text {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.navbar-light .navbar-text a {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.navbar-light .navbar-text a:hover, .navbar-light .navbar-text a:focus {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-brand {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-brand:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 5);
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.disabled {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 5);
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.show,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-toggler {
  color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.5);
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='30' height='30' viewBox='0 0 30 30'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.5)' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='3' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-text {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-text a {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-text a:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-text a:focus {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To reproduce the issue, I have copied and paste the content of the webpage you provided, made the changes you've pointed out and commented the code to help explain it: [CSS](https://pastebin.com/NVdzS77t) and [Index](https://pastebin.com/ZsPA6dYx)

1. Navbar togglers are left-aligned by default, it's possible to align them to the right by adding an element like the navbar-brand right above the button on index.htmL `<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>`
2. The active link color can be removed by deleting the word `active` from  `<li class="nav-item active">`
3. On css, add  `outline: revert;` to the `.button:focus` class in order to change the color of the button on mouse focus event